# how to get atrributes between classes

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello i have the following problem and i can`t find the way to move forward.

Create a "Client" class.

- It will have the attributes: "first name", "last name" and "country", which will be added in the builder.
- Creates a "Calendar" class.
- It will have a method called "createAppointment" to which a date and an object from the previously created "Client" class will be passed by parameter.
- It will have a method called "getAppointments" that will return an array with the appointments of the current month with the following format:

```
[
[0] =>
[
'customer' => "First name Last name"
'date' => "03-05-2018"
],
[1] =>
[
'customer' => "First name Last name"
'date' => "06-05-2018"
],
........
]
```

and this is my approach so far

```
"use strict"
class Client {
    constructor(name, lastname, country){
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.country = country;
    }
}
class calendar extends Client {
    createAppointment (date, name, lastname){
     this.date = date;
     super (name,lastname);


    }
    getAppointments(){
        new Array
    }

}
let Calendar = new calendar("george", "luco", "suiza");
```

Comment: You need to use { get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_meta_box_key', true ); } for print out the information of your meta box.

Comment: Please print the $query variable print_r($query) and check what meta_keys you are getting, If you're not getting key that related to your created attribute then please edit the any of post and find that attribute and updated its value and update the post then refresh again and check in $query var. I hope it would help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 :
 first get the post id inside the loop like
       `get_the_ID()  or the_ID(`);

```
var $post_id = get_the_ID()
```

Step 2 : Go to Database and find the meta_key coressponding customed attributes with the help of post id you get in the loop . [image]

Setp 3 : inside loop you easy get data with the help of meta key

```
get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```